# Modals switching between mobile and desktop

Tags: html, internet-explorer, viewport

my app is working well in all browsers but not on ie, exactly in IE 11.
When I open a modal, sometimes it open on desktop css version and others in mobile css version. It only happens in IE.

Is there a IE config problem that or some meta tags problem?

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="life-drainuse/images/favicon.png">  -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: could you share code with modals layout?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround will be trigger resize `event` in javascript, but it is not very good solution. I cannot give you better feedback but try workaround as hotfix. But if you will reproduce it in jsfiddle will be better